# jrean/laravel-user-verification not working on authenticated user

Tags: laravel

I am using jrean/laravel-user-verification on Laravel 5.6, one issue is that it doesn't verify users if the user is logged in. Only if the user is logged out does the link actually verify the user.

I can't see anything mentioned about this in the docs, and seems backwards as you can't resend verification email if the user isn't logged in either.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['getVerification', 'getVerificationError']]);

In construct